# Ruby log file doesn't work on Windows, but works on Mac OS?

Tags: ruby, windows, macos, logging

I wrote a script that operates on my Mac just fine. It has this line of code in it:

```
filename = "2011"
  File.open(filename, File::WRONLY|File::CREAT|File::EXCL) do |logfile|
    logfile.puts "MemberID,FirstName,LastName,BadEmail,gender,dateofbirth,ActiveStatus,Phone"
```

On Windows the script runs fine and it creates the logfile `2011`, but it doesn't actually `puts` anything to that logfile, so the file is created, the script runs, but the logging doesn't happen.

Does anyone know why? I can't think of what would have changed in the actual functionality of the script that would cause the logging to cease.

Comment: what version of ruby? Are you sure it's creating the file (i.e. delete it, it gets recreated?) If you have an extra output after this section like "puts 'done'" does it output that to the screen?

Comment: I'm using `ruby 1.9.3`. I have deleted the file and it does recreate it. I am using several `puts` commands before and after the logging, and they both get put to the screen.

Comment: Are you turning around and reading it within that block? This works for me: https://gist.github.com/rdp/6816673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for clarity I wouldn't use the flags to specify how to open/create the file. I'd use:

```
File.open(filename, 'a')
```

That's the standard mode for log-files; You want to create it if it doesn't exist, and you want to append if it does.

Logging typically requires writing to the same file multiple times through the running time of an application. People like to open the log and leave it open, but there's potential for problems if the code crashes before the file is closed or it gets flushed by Ruby or the OS. Also, the built-in buffering by Ruby and the OS can cause the file to buffer, then flush, which, when you're tailing the file, will make it jump in big chunks, which isn't much good if you're watching for something.

You can tell Ruby to force flushing immediately when you write to the file by setting [`sync = true`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D):

```
logfile = File.open(filename, 'a')
logfile.sync = true
logfile.puts 'foo'
logfile.close
```

You could use [`fsync`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-fsync-3D), which also forces the OS to flush its buffer.

The downside to forcing sync in either way is you negate the advantage of buffering your I/O. For normal file writing, like to a text file, don't use `sync` because you'll slow your application down. Instead let normal I/O happen as Ruby and the OS want. But for logging it's acceptable because logging should periodically send a line, not a big blob of text.

You could immediately [`flush`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-flush) the output, but that gets redundant and violates the DRY principle:

```
logfile = File.open(filename, 'a')
logfile.puts 'foo'
logfile.flush
logfile.puts 'bar'
logfile.flush
logfile.close
```

`close` flushes before actually closing the file I/O.

You can wrap your logging output in a method:

```
def log(text)
  File.open(log_file, 'a') do |logout|
    logout.puts(text)
  end
end
```

That'll open, then close, the log file, and automatically flush the buffer, and negate the need to use `sync`.

Or you could take advantage of Ruby's [Logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/index.html) class and let it do all the work for you.

Comment: Great information here. This is incredibly helpful, I was actually struggling to find out how to log in real time but this helps. The issue I was having was due to a difference between `ctrl+c` on mac and `ctrl+pause/break` on windows coupled with the above. The script was not closing the file, thus causing it to only push to the logfile when the script ended. When I used `ctrl+pause/break` on windows, the logfile wasn't filled with anything. But when I let the script finish on it's own, the logfile worked fine. Thanks for the tips.